# Alfresco Community edition-5.1 in workflow form text field show and hide for conditions

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I am using Alfresco Community Edition 5.1.x. I have created a workflow using kick-start where I have used drop-down list.

When selecting the drop-down value, text-field should be enabled based on conditions otherwise the text-field is not showing in workflow form.

Is this possible? And how?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. I've seen two choices :

1. Make the select choice a step in the workflow (you chose, you click next and the form appears)
2. You do it in javascript (what I have done). You put a callback on your select, and use jQuery `show()` and `hide()` functions. If you have mandatory fields, you nedd to handle that too.

This is what I've done and it worked, but I would be glad if anyone have a more elegant solution.

**Edit** : in my case, I was making a custom component, and then had a template (ftl) and a script file (js).
In this js, once the page is initialized, I added a section of code to handle what I need. The code I'm putting is just for the example :

```
$('#select_id').change(function(){
        showHideMyComponent($(this).val());
});

function showHideCible(value){
        boolean hide = checkIfIhaveToHide(value);
        if(hide){
            $("#divToHandle").hide();
        }else{
            $("#divToHandle").show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @KrutikJayswal What do you mean ?

Comment: Alfresco is CMS..there are lot many things to do..for this..its not only javascript sho and hide()

Comment: My solution is working, I'm showing/hiding parts of the form based on a sélect event by using JavaScript on my project. It works, even if I would like à builtin solution provided by alfresco.

Comment: Hi All, Above Java Script code is not working in pop-up. is there any solution for this.

Comment: Is your js included in the page ? Could you please edit your question with your code ?

Comment: My js code is there in the ftl file. that js code is not working only in case of pop-up.   I also make a new question regarding this. please refer below link.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37921968/java-script-code-is-not-working-in-property-page-pop-up?noredirect=1#comment63294704_37921968

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom FTL which will display the form fields according to dropdown selection
And you have to give the path of that ftl 
as your field id

`<field id="xxx:propName" set="info">
    <control template="/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/xyz.ftl" />
</field>`