# Java script code is not working in property page pop-up

Tags: alfresco-share

I wrote below code :

```
<control  template="/com/alfresco/components/form/controls/datatable-property.ftl">
    <control-param name="config">
        Select Party, Select Party, dropdown, ["Party1", "Party2", "Party3", "Party4"];
        Party Name, Party Name, dropdown, ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"];
        Party Constitution, Party Constitution, dropdown, ["corporation", "individual", "other"];
    </control-param>
</control>
```

Its working perfect on normal alfresco property page. But if we edit properties in pop-up, then same code is not working? 
please refer attached 2 different screen shots. its working in first but not in second case.[image]
how can i resolve this issue?

please reply.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Alfresco, ftl code is not working for some "Edit Properties" doclib actions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37894331/in-alfresco-ftl-code-is-not-working-for-some-edit-properties-doclib-actions)

Comment: Its similar, but i didn't get solution, so i posted it again in simple and user friendly manner. Please reply me, is there any way to do this or not??